# Is the skin of feline jungle predators protected against ants?

Tags: mammals, skin, feline

I was watching a video of a jaguar stalking along a riverbank, killing prey, climbing up the muddy bank, then laying in thick brush to eat. My first thought about this is that there must be tons of ants. I've never been to a jungle but on muddy river banks around where I live if you crawled around near the water and on the forest floor in general you'd be sure to get attacked by ants and it would result in hundreds of bites which cause swelling, major discomfort, and perhaps infection.

This seems like it would be a problem for large mammal jungle predators that kill prey in that kind of river bank area and then plop down and eat it. Does the fur make them immune to ant bites, or ants more rare in the jungle than I imagine, or they do get bitten but they just have a high tolerance for pain?